# zend paginator current, next elements

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination

I'm working in Zend Framework with pagination (using Zend Paginator). The problem is that I wanna get the first element and unset the previous element, somthing like

```
$elements = Zend_Paginator::factory($items);
$elements
                ->setCurrentPageNumber($this->view->getRequest()->getParam('page', 1))
                ->setItemCountPerPage(10)
                ->setPageRange(5);
```

using something like `current($elements)` or `next($elements); unset(previous($elements))` but doest not work Zend Paginator Object

Any idea? Zend Paginator has a similar method?

Comment: i believe you are using zend_paginator in the wrong way. It is intended only for use when displaying the data, you have to filter it before passing to the paginator. It is not intended to manipulate items but simply build a navigation.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own class method that would such as

```
$element->unsetElement();
```

or whatever, then have that handle whatever you need it to. I don't think you can use unset in the context your using it in.

Answer (score 0):

Does the $items variable contains the data you're planning on using?

If so, i recommend you remove the values before passing the array into the zend_paginator factory class:

```
unset($array[0]);
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator(new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Array($array));
```